# How do we tell react-rnd to pass an onClick event, sometimes it does, sometimes not

Tags: onclick, onmousedown

We have created containers that seem to be the same. We've added RnD to each. There is a close-icon in the upper right of each, with onClick attached. When I look at the Chrome Event Listeners, in some containers RnD passes a click through to our close icon, and in other containers it does not. We get the mousedown for both containers. RnD seems to be adding its classes the same on both. On the containers that do not work, doubleclick also doesn't come through either. Z-index doesn't matter. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to debug why some of the containers are working and others are not?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this has to do with propagation of the mouse up and down events. By putting a new wrapper that stops propagation, all the divs work well.

```
const PreserveFocusWrapper = ({ children }) => (    
  <div
    onMouseDown={(event) => { event.stopPropagation() }}
    onMouseUp={(event) => { event.stopPropagation() }}
  >
    { children }
  </div>
)
```

export default PreserveFocusWrapper

Apparently without this, the close icon (as a child) was not being passed the onClick or onMouseUp events.